# Prove $E[X/Y] > 1$ for $X,Y$ i.i.d. positive random variables.

Tags: probability

I am not sure how I can prove this statement. I have seen for the proof $E[X/Y] > 1$ for $X, Y$ i.i.d. positive random variables, but what should I do for strict inequality?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: $\frac 1  x$ is stricly convex on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} \ge 2$ for any $x,y > 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and the comments. I appreciate that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answered because this is an interesting question in its own right.**

First, $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is a convex function, so Jensen's Inequality gives
$${\bf{E}}\Big[\frac{1}{X}\Big] \ \ge \ \frac{1}{{\bf{E}}[X]}.$$

Next, as $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* random variables, so are $Y$ and $\frac{1}{X}$ independent random variables. This yields the equation:
$${\bf{E}}\Big[\frac{Y}{X}\Big] \ = \ {\bf{E}}[Y] \times {\bf{E}}\Big[\frac{1}{X}\Big].$$  So plugging in the previous inequality yields

$${\bf{E}}\Big[\frac{Y}{X}\Big] \ = \ {\bf{E}}[Y] \times{\bf{E}}\Big[\frac{1}{X}\Big]$$ $$\ge {\bf{E}}[Y] \times\frac{1}{{\bf{E}}[X]},$$
or in particular,
$${\bf{E}}\Big[\frac{Y}{X}\Big] \quad \ge \quad {\bf{E}}[Y] \times\frac{1}{{\bf{E}}[X]}.$$

Finally, as $Y$ and $X$ are identically distributed, it follows that the equation ${\bf{E}}[Y] = {\bf{E}}[X]$ holds. So plugging in this above yields
$${\bf{E}}\Big[\frac{Y}{X}\Big] \quad \ge \quad {\bf{E}}[Y] \times\frac{1}{{\bf{E}}[X]} = 1,$$
which is the desired result.

---

**NOTE** As $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is *strictly* convex, one has by Jensen's *strict* inequality iff $X$ does not take only one value almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Your note at the end helped me to understand now. I have noticed that I missed that point.